# How would one solve the conjecture that for any odd n, there is a twin prime between $n^2$ and $(n+2)^2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

How would one solve the conjecture that for any odd n, there is a twin prime between $n^2$ and $(n+2)^2$?

Examples, for $n=3$, there is a twin prime between 9 and 25 of (11,13).
For $n=9$, there is a twin prime between 81 and 121 of (101,103).

Comment: Since it is even not known whether there are infinitely many twin primes, speculation on the methods of proof of something even stronger is likely dubious.

Comment: Why would you imagine that this is easier than the Twin Prime Conjecture?

Comment: Already, it is not easy at all to show that there is a prime between n and 2n (just a prime, not à twin prime)

Comment: One approach is to assume there is a twin prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ and thus the conjecture follows easily.

Comment: You could prove it false by exhibiting an $n$ where it fails.  That would not mean settling the twin prime conjecture because there could still be an infinite number of them, just a hole in the distribution.

Comment: $n=-1$ need to be excluded, if the claim is for any odd.

Comment: The statement is stronger than the twin-prime-conjecture, so it is very unlikely that someone can prove the conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I wrote & ran a fairly simple program to check certain information regarding how many twin primes there are between $n^2$ and $\left(n + 2\right)^2$ for odd natural numbers $n$. I ran this for $n$ up to a million, i.e., $100000$, so the square goes up to a trillion. For each range of billion integers (apart from the last one due to a small coding limitation), I output the cumulative minimum, maximum & average of the # of twin primes in each $n^2$ to $\left(n + 2\right)^2$ range. The minimum value of $1$ first occurs for $n = 21$, but I didn't check if it occurred again afterwards. The maximum value goes up for each billion initially, but then sometimes doesn't change for a span of quite a few billion. At the end, it is $7207$. The average seems to always be increasing fairly steadily, but slower later on. At the end, it is about $3739.588515$.

This indicates your conjecture appears to be plausible, but it's obviously not a proof. As Mostafa Ayaz states, the twin prime conjecture is not proven so we don't even know for sure that there's an infinite # of twin primes, much less at least one between each $n^2$ and $\left(n + 2\right)^2$ range.

Comment: Thank you very much! You went well beyond what I was expecting for an answer. Since it is a plausible conjecture but unsolvable, can I call it the "Watanabe Conjecture" and maybe it will become a famous conjecture like the Goldbach conjecture?

Comment: @tempwatts You are welcome. You can certainly call it whatever you want and, you never know, it may become a famous conjecture some day.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

According to [Twin primes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), the number of twin prime couples is unknown (even whether they are finite or infinite). If your statement holds true, then as a consequence you have proved that **there are infinitely many twin primes** which is yet unsolved. Your question then sounds very encouraging as a rush to solve this old and interesting conjecture!